# Personal Token not working in github workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

I have 2 repos. One is responsible for the main code and the second one is where things are deployed. (`<name>.github.io`). To make my life easier I had made a workflow that would take my main code, build it and pushes it into the Github-Page branch of the other repo.

It was working for quite a while but 2-3 months ago it stopped working. Below is a snippet of code where the error is occurring.

Workflow code (breaks at the last line)

```
git init
git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
git remote add origin "https://${{ secrets.AUTH_TOKEN_FOR_DEPLOYMENT }}@github.com/<name>/<name>.github.io.git"
```

Error:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Few things I have tried

- Refreshing my token (didn't work)
- ad-m/github-push-action (only worked for force push and I didn't want that)
- Looking all over google (only came across solutions I have already tried)
- Asking on reddit (no response)

Comment: PS: The real name has been replaced with <name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that when `checkout@v3` was rolled out it broke the code that was written with `checkout@v2` for some reason. Hence the simple solution to this problem is to update the `checkout` and `setup-node` version to `v3` instead of `v2`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is a side effect of [introducing fine-grained personal access tokens](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/).

If so, try and replace your old token by a fine-grained one, which would be limited to your target repository (the one you want to push to from your GitHub Action).

Or try and use (registered as a GitHub Action secret) a deploy token, also limited to your target repository.

Comment: Sadly, I am getting the same error for both of your solutions

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer OK, glad you have found a solution.